# how to format float number in python?

Tags: python, format

I want to format my float number with 2 digit after decimal.

```
>>> x =5.0
>>> y=float("{:0.2f}".format(x))
>>> y
5.0
```

i want my output in this format:

```
5.00
```

Comment: good answer on stackoverflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/455612/limiting-floats-to-two-decimal-points)

Answer (score 6):

For newer version of python you can use:

```
x = 5.0
print(f' x: {x:.2f}')
```

out put will be:

```
x: 5.00
```

for more about this style see: [f-string](https://cito.github.io/blog/f-strings/)

Answer (score 3):

You can do it by

```
In [11]: x = 5

In [12]: print("%.2f" % x)
5.00

In [13]:
```

Answer (score 2):

Your answer was correct. you just misplaced the colon:

```
print "{:.2f}".format(5.0)

 #output:
'5.00'
```

;)

Comment: what notation is this? **In [14]:**

Comment: Its a line number from an  ipython console